# Deleted myself from Facebook group and cannot regain access

Tags: facebook-groups

I created a closed group and was the sole administrator. Somehow I deleted myself from the group and cannot regain access because I am the person that admits people to the group. What can I do to resolve this issue without having to delete the group? There are so many members, I won't be able to re invite them.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Facebook FAQ - [How can I become a group admin?](https://www.facebook.com/help/121869921229278/)

> You're automatically an admin if you create a group. Otherwise, if you join a group that already has one or more admins, you can ask any of the existing admins to add you as an admin. **If you're a member of a group with no admins, you can become an admin by clicking Make Me Admin under Members in the right column.**

However, it appears that Facebook needs to update this FAQ, since there's no longer a right column with a Members sections.  Instead, the Make Me Admin option is now under the settings icon (looks like a gear) at the top right of the group page.

So, you will need to privately contact one of your group members and ask him/her to become an admin using the instructions above.  He or she will then be able to add you to the group and make you an admin again.

> [How do I add more admins to my group?](https://www.facebook.com/help/148640791872225/)
>
> - Click on the About tab
> - Find a member by scrolling through the page or entering a name in the search box
> - Click Make Admin under the name of the member you wish to add as an admin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Facebook behaves when the admin leaves a group, but its possible that it may assign admin to another user (maybe who ever joined 2nd). If you know anyone who is a member of the group in real life then I'd ask them if they can see who is admin.

Otherwise you can report a problem with groups here by following the **Tell us More** link at the bottom of this page: https://www.facebook.com/help/issues/groups

Answer (score 0):

If you delete yourself, or something happens to your account, you remain as a "ghost" admin; meaning the group will still show 1 admin under the member's list, however, no names will be listed.  This prevents an active group from being immediately deleted, however, I've yet to find a way to regain or reconnect as the admin.

Answer (score -2):

I think that when you delete yourself, it deletes the group if you made the group and were the only administrator.