# Adding users to a Facebook Messenger group after the sole admin leaves

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

This question is very similar to this one: [Deleted myself from Facebook group and cannot regain access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31390/deleted-myself-from-facebook-group-and-cannot-regain-access) but specifically for a Facebook *Messenger* chat.

I was the sole admin of a Facebook Messenger chat, left the chat, and now no one can add me back because no one else is an admin. When someone tries it says `new people need to be approved by admins`, but there are no admins listed.

Can anyone promote themselves to be the new admin or is there another workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Any member of the existing chat can make themselves an admin. As of June 2020, this can *only* be done via the web interface at [messenger.com](https://messenger.com), *not* the mobile app.

The option to do this looks like this:

[image]